# How to change a p tag to input field when onclick event is performed using react?

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a react component and my requirement is to convert a p tag to input tag when it's clicked and when I click the input tag it should convert back to the p tag.

Please help me to solve this?

Comment: `when clicked again.`. The p tag was change to input tag?.What clicked?

Comment: when I click the p tag it should convert to input tag and again when I click the input tag, it should  convert back to p tag.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to like that?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-https-jpjlk?file=/src/App.js

Comment: There's one problem sir, when I try to type anything in the input tag, it's getting converted back to p tag . any suggestions where I could type in the input tag and can change it to p tag.

Comment: Update: <input autoFocus /> should be used to type in the input field right away.

Comment: so when do you want to convert the input to p tag? yes autofocus will help on the typing, do you got your solution?

Comment: Yes, my problem has been solved. when I click on the input field, it should convert and I should be able to type. autoFocus has solved the problem.